# ng repeat after postDigest not working

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to load data from list to repeater but its not working the data is returning, list of students but its not showing on screen.

**Controller:**

```
$scope.students=[];

 $scope.$$postDigest(function () {
     $http.get("/getAllStudents"/*, {timeout: canceler.promise}*/).
     then(function (response, status, headers, config) {                        
         if (response.data) {
             $scope.students=response.data;   
 }
    });

 });
```

**HTML:**

```
  <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
    <td contenteditable="true">{{student.Id}}</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">{{student.FullName}}</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">{{student.Gender}}</td>       
    <td contenteditable="true">{{student.Grade}}</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="student in students track by $index"> Try it

Answer (score 0):

When the `$http.get` the call is made in the `postDigest`, it seems the data is successfully inserted inside the `$scope.students`.  Please check if there is any `scope` issue, because as per the details provided, it should work until and unless you're missing to mention any other details.

Comment: I don't think a `scope.apply` should be done in the case mentioned by OP. Since `$http` is an angular service, it will trigger the `digest` cycle after the data is fetched. Calling `scope.apply` unnecessarily will tax you application

Comment: Yeah @ClydeLobo.. Missed that.  As `$http` is a service, angular triggers a `digest` cycle after the result is fetched. Calling `scope.apply` is not needed.